# Index on JSON_TABLE

Tags: json, oracle, indexing, plsql

We have an input to a PL/SQL procedure which is a clob object, which is actually a JSON
So, we have something like `SELECT a1  FROM JSON_TABLE (p_input,'$' ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY COLUMNS ( NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS( a1 NUMBER(18) PATH '$.a1', a2 VARCHAR2(10) PATH '$.a2')))`

Using the above select we need to perform some selects,updates to some tables. However, this is going for a full table scan because there is no index.

As this clob is not a part of any table,but an input to procedure, we cannot add json search indexes or other indexes to this. Is there anyway we can add indexes to a standalone json_table which is not a part of any actual table / table column?

Any inputs appreciated.

I tried adding index via EXECUTE IMMEDIATE something like this

`declare v_string clob; v_string1 varchar2(900); BEGIN v_string1 :=  q'{CREATE SEARCH INDEX idx_json_search ON JSON_TABLE(}'||'v_string'||q'{,'$'  ERROR ON ERROR NULL ON EMPTY COLUMNS ( NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS( a1  NUMBER(18) PATH '$.a1', a2 DATE PATH '$.a2' ) ) ) (a1) FOR JSON  ; }' ; execute immediate v_string1 ; end;` 
But the above did not work and not able to add indexes to this standalone json_table

Comment: json_table is not a table.  I don't think there is anything you can do

Comment: 1. Create temporary table of required structure, parse JSON once, insert into that table and then use the table with all table benefits. 2. Use multitable insert instead of multiple separate operations. 3. Parse everything once into local collection and use `forall`

Comment: You cannot create indexes on dynamic objects.